# Why Array + Array equals empty string?

Tags: javascript

I've seen this pretty funny [screencast](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) yesterday about some oddities in languages like Ruby and Javascript and the guy shows that:

```
[] + [] -> ""  // returns empty string
```

not very obvious...

I've decided to go to the [ECMAscript language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) to get more info. I've started with the `+` operator implementation (p.75) which says:

> **11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )**
>
> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric addition.
>   The production AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression is evaluated as follows:
>   1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
>   2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
>   3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
>   4. Let rval be GetValue(rref) .
>   5. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
>   6. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
>   7. If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>   a. Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)
>   8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim). See the  Note below 11.6.3.
>
> NOTE1 No hint is provided in the calls to ToPrimitive in steps 5 and 6. All native ECMAScript objects except Date  objects handle the absence of a hint as if the hint Number were given; Date objects handle the absence of a hint as if the  hint String were given. Host objects may handle the absence of a hint in some other manner.
>
> NOTE 2 Step 7 differs from step 3  of the comparison algorithm for the relational operators (11.8.5), by using  the  logical-or operation instead of the logical-and operation.

My guess was that the point 7 was reached in some way through different evaluations/conversions as described before but I cannot figure out what is really happenning...

Can someone provide a much straightforward explanation for this ?

---

I'm willing to understand all this a bit better in order to try to answer why:

```
[] + {} -> [object Object]
{} + [] -> 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 2. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).

Since no hint is provided to `ToPrimitive`:

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of  O is called with no
>   hint, then it behaves as if the hint were  Number, unless O is a Date
>   object (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were
>   String.

So it's same as calling with a Number hint:

```
When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with hint Number, the following steps are taken:
1. Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
2. If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then, a. Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and  an empty argument list. b. If val is a primitive value, return val.
3. Let toString be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "toString".
4. If IsCallable(toString) is true then, a. Let str be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of toString, with O as the this value and  an empty argument list. b. If str is a primitive value, return str.
5. Throw a TypeError exception.
```

Since the return value of `[].valueOf()` is not a primitive, it goes to `[].toString()` which returns `""`.

This same applies for object objects, except the `.toString` of an object returns `[object Object]` while `.toString` of an array returns `.join(",")`

---

`{} + []`

The `{}` is not treated as an object here but as an empty block. So the code that runs is:

```
{}
+[]; //Same as +[] ( Number([]) ) which is 0
```

To resolve the ambiguity and get normal result from `{} + []` use

`({}) + []` or `({} + [])`

Funny code:

```
{} ! [] //false
({}) ! [] //SyntaxError
```

Comment: Makes more sense now. The specification can be pretty though to get into but got some leads now. Thanks.

Comment: @DidierGhys yep, careful with object literal, javascript is very eager to treat them as blocks wherever it can.